# tf.data.Dataset - delete cache?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is it possible to delete the in-memory cache that's built after calling `tf.data.Dataset.cache()`?

Here's what I'd like to do. The augmentation for the dataset is very costly, so the current code is more or less:

```py
data = tf.data.Dataset(...) \
       .map(<expensive_augmentation>) \
       .cache() \
       # .shuffle().batch() etc.
```

However, this means that every iteration over `data` will see the same augmented versions of the data samples. What I'd like to do instead is to use the cache for a couple of epochs and then start over, or equivalently do something like `Dataset.map(<augmentation>).fleeting_cache().repeat(8)`. Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: I would also like to do this, but instead of throwing away the whole cache every n epochs, I would like to evict a certain percentage of the cache on every epoch.

Comment: FTR, I created a [feature request for this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/54157).

Answer (score 1):

The cache lifecycle is tied to the dataset, so you can achieve this by re-creating the dataset:

```py
def create_dataset():
  dataset = tf.data.Dataset(...)
  dataset = dataset.map(<expensive_augmentation>)
  dataset = dataset.shuffle(...)
  dataset = dataset.batch(...)
  return dataset

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
  # Drop the cache every 8 epochs.
  if epoch % 8 == 0: dataset = create_dataset()
  for batch in dataset:
    train(batch)
```